# Distribute iPhone app to testers?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store-connect

I am working on my iphone app and now I want to send my app to my testers. But how should I send it to them ? Plus, they don't have an Xcode. Is it necessary?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at Test Flight. We are currently using it and it offers a lot of great tools and is very easy to set up.

[testflightapp.com](http://www.testflightapp.com)

It distributes it adhoc and then you can push it directly to the testers and allows you to see install statuses. Time spent and other analytic tools.

To answer your other questions. The don't need Xcode. They just need to have their UDID registered on your apple account. They will get sent an email that will ask to download the latest release. The app then installs over the air.

Answer (score 5):

Since iOS 4.0, users have been able to install Ad-Hoc apps over the air. Please note you're required to get the testers' device UDIDs and add them to your device list on developer.apple.com and to the app's the provisioning profile.

You can host the IPA yourself, but I would recommend using [TestFlightApp.com](http://testflightapp.com/).

[Macworld wrote a decent article](http://www.macworld.com/article/1157311/testflight.html) about the gist of it, and TestFlight is fairly straightforward to use, especially since it allows you to send an email or link to your testers and collect the needed UDID from them.

Answer (score 4):

Try [diawi](http://diawi.com).
I find it very simple and very friendly to use. Also there is no wait in the queue type *registration stuff*. When you open it just drag and drop the .ipa file and the provisioning profile. To verify whether or not your app has been installed, just add your email id in the field mentioned and you will get a confirmatory email about your app installation. For installation at the tester's end they simply need Safari to install the app and the profile.

**Below are the steps to create .ipa file (xcode 4.2)**

Select iOS Device>Go to Product>Archive>Share>Choose iOS App Store Package (.ipa)>Provide a path to save.

Easily done!!!

Comment: Thank you very much ! I didn't know how to create an .ipa file on xcode 4.2 but now I did it and uploaded on the webpage. Thanks a lot !

Comment: @ArshadCan you pls tell me that using diawi, is it neccessary to add device's UDID for distributing an application using enterprise? thanks

Answer (score 1):

From 26 feb 15 Testflight is closed their service...

I have used new link for creating installation link of ipa and distribute link to your client, tester etc.

1. open this link

   http://www.diawi.com/index.php
2. upload provisioning profile(drag and drop) to their dashboard.
3. upload ipa(drag and drop) to their dashboard.
4. click on send button.
   after that copy generated link and share to your client and tester.

Comment: TestFlight was bought by Apple and is now available at https://testflight.apple.com

Answer (score 0):

With iOS 8, Xcode 6, iTunes Connect and TestFlight you don't need UDIDs and Ad Hocs anymore. You will just need an Apple ID from your beta tester. Right now you can only beta test your app with 25 internal testers, but soon 1000 external testers will be available too. This blog post show you how to set up a beta test with internal testers,

http://blog.thebetafamily.com/2014/09/10/testflight-beta-testing-ios-8/